# SQL server 2008: How to get the start date and end date of my data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

As a newb, I already know that I will be berated for asking this question, but I did not find the answer on the site here and could use some help...

I have a table that lists data by the day, and by type.  For example

```
Transaction  |  Date  | Type
-----------------------------
Updat    | 11/7/2008  | Cash-out
Update   | 11/10/2008 | Wrote-check 
Deposit  | 11/11/2009 | Cashed Check 
Update   | 11/18/2008 | Wrote check 
Deposit  | 11/19/2009 | Cashed Check
```

---

What I'm trying to do, is find the very first occurrence of each transaction type, and the very last occurrence of each transaction type.
so I'm trying to figure out an sql statement that I can write that will return something like this:

```
Transaction  |  First Date  | Last Date  |
----------------------------------------------
Update       | 11/7/2008    | 11/18/2008 |
Deposit      | 11/11/2009   | 1/19/2009  |
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
     transaction,
     MIN([date]) AS [First Date],
     MAX([date]) AS [Last Date]
FROM
     My_Table
GROUP BY
     transaction
```

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT Transaction, Min([date])  AS [First Date] , Max([Date]) AS [Last Date]
FROM myTable GROUP BY Transaction
```